# Utilizing Poppler and Django in Digital Ocean App

Tags: python, django, python-tesseract, poppler, pdf2image

I am having issues with Poppler playing nice with the DigitalOcean Apps.
I have a Django Web App that I have built and I have an automation script that I want to run.  This script takes the text file reads the file and then puts the contents into a db field for a user text search function.

It will work on my local machine, but it will not run.  I get a `PDFInfoNotInstalledError`.  In researching that error it states that Poppler is not installed and will need to be installed.  Digital Ocean will not let you do an apt install from the console.  I created an aptfile to install poppler.  I was asked by DO support to add it in the `requirement.txt` file.  I did that and added the path to the `$PATH` variables.  Still was getting the same error.  Unsure on what to do next can someone help me with this issue?[image: DO Console Error]

I have tried to add poppler to the server, I have tried adding a python package for poppler.  I was expecting for this to be recognized so that the OCR tool could work.